# Leaflet / Mapbox - Drag & Drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, leaflet, mapbox, marker

I have a web based map that is using Mapbox / Leaflet JS API.

On the map, I have several stationary markers and other markers that I am moving around based on GPS data that is pushed to the browser. When a moving marker is dropped on a stationary marker, I want to identify the two markers that were involved.

I have implemented a handler for the moving marker's "dragend" event which enables me to identify the marker that was dragged/dropped.

My questions is, how can I identify the marker that it was dropped on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite hard to do, because the only thing that lets you correctly identify a marker is it's latitude/longitude position. So if you try to drop a marker onto a marker with lat/lng 0,0, you need to drop it exactly onto that position which will turn out to be a very hard thing to do.

You could ofcourse build some sort of tolerance into it, but that tolerance will need to vary according to zoom level which i think will be very hard to get right. You could do something like this:

```
// Drag has ended
marker.on('dragend', function (e) {

  // Get position of dropped marker
  var latLng = e.target.getLatLng();

  // Object to hold nearest marker and distance
  var nearest = {};

  // Loop over layer which holds rest of the markers
  featureLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {

    // Calculate distance between each marker and dropped marker
    var distance = latLng.distanceTo(layer.getLatLng());

    // Set the first as nearest
    if (!nearest.marker) {
      nearest.marker = layer;
      nearest.distance = distance;

    // If this marker is nearer, set this marker as nearest
    } else if (distance < nearest.distance) {
      nearest.marker = layer;
      nearest.distance = distance;
    }

  });

});
```

Example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GDixNNDGqW9rvO4R1dku?p=preview

Now the `nearest` object will hold the marker that is closest to your drop position. Closest distance may vary according to your zoom level. When you're at zoom level 1, it may look like you've dropped it exactly on the other marker but you could be thousands of miles off. At zoom 18 the difference will be much smaller, but to drop it exactly on the same lat/lng is virtually impossible. Otherwise you could simply compare all the latlng's against the dropped latlng but that won't work in practice.

So now you have the nearest marker and it's distance to the dropped marker you could implement tolerance, something along the lines of: `if (nearest.distance < (x / y))` where `x` is the distance and `y` the zoomlevel.  It's something you'll need to play with to get right. Once you've figured out the correct tolerance you could implement it right along with the distance comparison in the handler.

Good luck, hope this helps

Comment: ...Many years later ... Markers don't just have the lat/lon to distinguish from the next marker. The layer that holds the markers, if you're using something like a geoJSON layer, will have a _leaflet_id